# R Sum 11th to N record of a column into the 11th record

Tags: r, sum, row

**The Problem:** I have the following issue. In R I create summary statistics for a variable and order them from highest to lowest value. The number of records (rows) can range from 20 to 100 depending on the variable. In order to create the desired output, I have to take the first 10 rows from the R output then for rows 11 to N I have to sum it up in Excel and add the resulting record as the 11th variable to my list. This is very inefficient as I have to keep going between Excel and R and would prefer to do it in R itself.

**R Code**

```
one = aggregate(rail11$Tons,rail11['STCC4'],sum) 
answer = data.frame(Commodity=one$STCC4, PATons=one$x) 
answer1 <- answer[order(-answer$PATons), ] # Sort it from Highest to lowest
# answer2 <- answer1[1:10,] # This line takes only the top 10 records
write.table(answer1, "testdata.csv",sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
```

I have uploaded the actual output and desired output to google drive so that you can test the code.

**Output from R code:** Actual actual from R code:  [Testdata.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0hTmthiX5dpRUREUDRsZ21GMDA/edit?usp=sharing)

**Desired Output from R:** Desired output from R: [sumrow.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0hTmthiX5dpVUNWZURkZ2FsRGM/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Krishnan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you dealing with just one column at a time? It seems not. Try

```
answer2[11,] <- apply(answer1[11:dim(answer1)[1], ], 2, sum)
```

Also

```
answer2[11,] <- colSums(answer1[11:dim(answer1)[1], ])
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for the code and help. Slightly modified the code to give the right answer.

Comment: No problem. If you tell me what I had wrong, I can update my answer for future viewers.

Comment: Updated as per your suggestion. Thanks.